# chi2 cumulative probability calculation without statistic toolbox matlab

Tags: matlab

I really need to calculate some cumulative probability of the chi2 (degree of freedom 1000)distribution. I know there is this function chi2cdf(x,n) in the corresponding statistics Toolbox in Matlab. However I don't have this specific Toolbox, can anyone help me with that?? 
It would be great if you can help me with that! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4779-chi-square-test) submission from the File Exchange which seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that is what I am looking for, I don't do test (hence there is no data available). I just want to find out the cumulative probability to certain point with certain degree of freedom. It shall be calculated withing the function chi2cdf(1,1000) if I had the corresponding Toolbox